# How to get sequence number in windchill through API

Tags: java, delphi, ptc-windchill

How to get sequence number for `WT.Part` or `Wt.Document` in Windchill through API?

When I create `WT.Part` - number automatically generated. But I can not find any method that returns the next number. I'm using `Info*Engine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution - create a new `Part`, read the number and either use it or delete.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of object `WTPart` creation windchill use OOTB oracle_seqence in order to auto generate the number.
The sequence name is mentioned in the `OIR` of respective object.
Like 
For

`WTPart` it is : `WTPARTID_seq`

For

`WTDocument` it is : `WTDOCUMENTID_seq`
etc .

So, if you want to get next number of `WTPart` then you can directly call the method `wt.fc.PersistenceHelper.manager.getNextSequence("WTPARTID_seq");`
from your info*engine task.

For different object the name of the sequence will be different.

In `10.2` PTC introduce another method `getCurrentSequence("SEQ_NAME")` to get the current sequence value without incrementing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familar with using Java with InfoEngine? If so, you can get the sequence by:

```
wt.fc.PersistenceHelper.manager.getNextSequence("SEQUENCE_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_OBJECT")
```

The sequence number will be specified inside the "Object Initialization Rule" that is associated with your object type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use `SOAP` to communicate with `Windchill` server. I have not found a method for generating a sequence